# Can I Run Windows Service with Quartz scheduler on 2 machines?

Tags: windows-services, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, quartz.net-2.0, windows-clustering

- Is this available in the free version? or if in Enterprise version, any details/guide to install it?
- How does Quartz pick up the jobs? Is it possible that both instances run the same job?
- If a job is still executing, and the trigger happens, will the job execute in a separate thread, can I avoid this? I mean if there is a job in progress, next trigger should wait for job finish first. How can I achieve this?

I am exploring this option to share the load between multiple Windows Service so that only one server does not have the load. I am new to this kind of architecture, so I am open to learning. Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't reinvent the wheel.

https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/tree/master/server/Quartz.Server

Second

Use the above code........and point it to the same ADO.NET datasource for the quartz.net configuration.

Comment: Your answer does not help in anyway.

Comment: Are you saying you tried the above approach, and it didn't work?